# Android Baidu push doesn't work with WiFi but works with cellular data

Tags: android, push-notification, baidu

I have an Android app implemented which uses the Baidu push service. Baidu SDK version is **50** (jar lib is **pushservice-5.0.0.66.jar**).
Currently I see strange behavior: I get successful response in onBind (so I receive Baidu token). But if I use Wifi data, the app won't create a socket for Baidu.

With Baidu's debug mode enabled, I see this error:

```
com....:bdservice_v1 E/BDPushSDK-PushConnection: Create socket err, errno: 2socketfd: -1
com....:bdservice_v1 I/BDPushSDK-PushConnection: disconnectedByPeer, mStoped == false
com....:bdservice_v1 I/BDPushSDK-PushConnection: destroy
com....:bdservice_v1 I/BDPushSDK-PushConnection: Schedule retry-- retry times: 2 time delay: 30000*
```

It is hard to find any info about all these errors (this is all seems to be in Chinese). But seems that the Error 2 says smth like: "No such file or directory". Also I was getting before: Error 110 "Connection timed out". So this is not really helpful.

But the thing is that everything works when using cellular data.
It doesn't look like any local settings for my network, as many users report the same issue for WiFi.

```
com....:bdservice_v1 D/BDPushSDK-PushConnection: create Socket ok
com....:bdservice_v1 D/BDPushSDK-PushSDK: heartbeat set : 180 secs
```

Comment: Finally it appears to be a bug valid for specific version of Baidu SDK + Android SDK only. With newer versions of Baidu Push SDK see this problem no more.

Comment: Am using cordova for Baidu Push Plugin ..  I am also facing same issue .. any thoughts ?

Comment: am still unable to receive message from baidu in WIFI .. not frequent